# Loading an Webpage into Flash file using Action Script 3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript

I am creating a training about financial aid for college students. I have been creating the training in Flash using AS3. I want to be able to pull in the FAFSA.ed.gov website into the Flash file. On the left hand side I have the menu of topics to review, and on the center to right side of the stage I am looking to use the AS3 equivalent to an html iframe.

What can I use in AS3 to load a full webpage into the Flash file? I have done a ton of searching and haven't found much.

Thanks!

BJ Griffin

Comment: You can't load a web page into Flash, in a web browser. There is the HTMLLoader that simion314 links to, but that is for AIR applications only. In the Flash Player plugin running in a web browser, you simply can't load a web page.

Comment: Ok cool, what would the script look like to pull in the following: http://fafsa.ed.gov

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out `HTMLLoader`. Is this what you need?  Read the documentation about the security restriction to make sure you can accomplish what you need.

[`HTMLLoader` Live Docs](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/html/HTMLLoader.html)

Comment: Ok cool, Thank you! What would the script look like to pull in the following: http://www.fafsa.ed.gov ?

Comment: @user3375807 if you read the documentation then you will find the load method , also there is an HTML component, the documentation also has examples so do the research

Comment: So I created the file as an Air file using Flash CC, but the swf file will not open... It works in the air package, but the actual swf file wont open independently... do you know why?